# Advanced Menu on AsideFirst is cut off

Tags: orchardcms

I've got an Advanced Menu in my Orchard CMS project.
First I had it in Navigation Zone and everything was fine until it became too wide, so I decided to move it to AsideFirst Zone and make it vertical.
But when I moved it I discovered that my menu is cut off by AsideFirst zone, the div element with class "zone-aside-first", to be exactly.
Whatever you do it stays inside that div and menu items that supoused to overlay other zones as it was in navzone are cut off.
I've tried to play with css style but it didn't help.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The answer happened to be very simple.

To solve the problem I just added a css style to AsideFirst Zone.

```
#aside-first { overflow: visible !important; }
```